# Akka Http getFromFile and getFromDirectory return 404

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am trying to build a simple REST API server that can also serve UI. i have. created a route to serve the files

```
pathPrefix("static") {
        getFromDirectory("tmp")
      }
```

however when I am sending

> http://localhost/static or  http://localhost/static/html.index

i am getting 404. when i replace it to `complete("hello")` i am getting the hello and it is fine. Also putting the full location doesnt help, either in dev mode via sbt and even when i build it as docker

what is the trick?

Comment: What is `getFromDirectory`?

Comment: I have the same problem, I create a directoty to serve some htmls and when I use getFromDirectory("public") I get 404 but if I use getFromFile("public/index.html") it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be localization of your file.

If your files are in the directory in the main directory of project use getFromDirectory directive.

If your files are in the directory in resources directory use getFromResourceDirectory directive.

Simple example below.

Routing:

```
val route = pathPrefix("staticTopLevel") {
    getFromDirectory("tmp")
  } ~ pathPrefix("staticResources") {
    getFromResourceDirectory("tmp")
  }
```

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

http://localhost:8080/staticTopLevel/my-top-level-file.txt => OK

http://localhost:8080/staticTopLevel/my-resource-file.txt => 404

http://localhost:8080/staticResources/my-resource-file.txt => OK

http://localhost:8080/staticResources/my-top-level-file.txt => 404